# (char *) (msg +1) where does this +1 takes us to?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, char

I am seeing a code, in which I have a statement `(char *)(emsg+1)` is given,

I guess `(char *) emsg` might have been a string, but what does this `+ 1` do here?

Comment: It depends on the type of `emsg`, but it appears that it is doing pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`emsg` is a pointer to some type (e.g. `int`). `emsg + 1` increments the pointer with 1, i.e. points to the initial address + `sizeof(int)`. Then, `(char*) (emsg + 1)` is a cast, i.e. the end result is casted to a `char*` pointer, so you end up with a pointer-to-char that points to initial address + `sizeof(int)`.

In general, `char*` are pointers to characters, i.e. `C`-like zero terminated strings, but this is not always the case. You often convert a pointer to `char*` when you want to "extract" the smallest unit of addressable memory, as on most machines `char*` is a pointer to an underlying type of one byte (`char`).

Comment: to clarify, when you say "+ sizeof(int)", you mean "advanced by sizeof(int) bytes".

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes, indeed, I meant `+` as "add to", or "advance".

Comment: so we can also write (char *)(emsg+sizeof(int))

Comment: What would happen if we write (char *)(emsg+1)+1 , the last one is out of bracket.

Comment: @BhavyaArora a pointer has an type, so when you do `emsg + n`, the pointer "knows" to advance by `n` times the size of of the underlying type. So, in your case, if you do `emsg + sizeof(int)`, then the pointer advances by `sizeof(int) * sizeof(int)`, which is not what you want. There is no need (and it is actually incorrect) to use `sizeof` when incrementing a pointer, the type of the pointer dictates with how many bytes the pointer "jumps" when you increment it.

Comment: @BhavyaArora regarding the second comment, `(char *)(emsg+1)+1` is decomposed as  `(char *)(emsg+1)`, which is a pointer to `char`, to which you add `1`. Because you add 1 to a pointer to `char`, you advance by one additional byte. So, at the end, `emsg` points to the initial address + `sizeof(int)` + 1 byte. If initial address is e.g. 0x0000, and `sizeof(int)=4` (as on most platforms), then `emsg` is pointing to the address location 0x0005. Hope this clarifies the issue.